# lazy-load database 'C:/RPackages/Weibull/pillar/R/pillar.rdb' is corrupt

Tags: r

I am using `flexsurv` package for fitting Weibull distribution parameters. I was getting an error that loadnamspace not found for Pillar and crayon. I installed pillar and crayon packages using devtools from github.

```
devtools::install_github("r-lib/crayon")
devtools::install_github("r-lib/pillar")
```

Now I am getting below mentioned error about pillar.rdt is corrupt. Please help me how to resolve it.

> Error : package or namespace load failed for 'flexsurv' in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env): lazy-load database 'C:/RPackages/Weibull/pillar/R/pillar.rdb' is corrupt"

Comment: Maybe mention what OS you are using, and if you have a working network.